# Detecting Presence of Horizontal Scrollbar in all browsers

Tags: javascript, testing, browser, selenium, scrollbar

I'm testing a web application. This web application should never have a horizontal scrollbar (as it resizes automatically). I want to test whether or not the horizontal bar exists (it should not).

Is this possible to do with JavaScript or even Selenium?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check whether HTML element has scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880381/check-whether-html-element-has-scrollbars)

Answer (score 0):

Try using scrollWidth and clientWidth properties.
See [this](http://bytes.com/groups/javascript/157924-detect-if-scrollbars-visible-inside-div) thread for more info