# How to adapt width when a div is scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with `width: 400px;` and `overflow: auto`. Is it possible to adapt the width of the div when the scrollbar is displayed ?

See example : [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/yzngV/2/) (resize the "Result" box up and down)

I'd prefer a css solution.

Comment: Scrollbar is rendered within bounds of `div#container`. Is it you want `div#container` to extend its width to 420px or similar so its scrollbar isn't covering contained fixed-width elements `div.content`?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Increase the width of the `container` div if the scrollbar is displayed so that it doesn't cover the `content`.

Comment: I don't think there is any CSS-only solution to this ... my best bet is having custom scrollbar implementation using Javascript to be rendered next to the div rather than within its bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
min-width: size;
```

on the container css. Where size is 400px + scrollbar width.

Take a look at **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yzngV/4/)**.

## Edit

I can't find how make it possibile with css only, sorry.
But checking if your div has scrollbar enabled, you can apply min-width attribute and it work.

**[Test here](http://jsfiddle.net/6qfvB/1/)** and let me know.

In your case, I think you have to do the hasScrollBar() test anyway happens something, such as window-resize or something else.

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/6qfvB/2/) works on event window resize.

Comment: In your demo the `overflow-y` is equal to `scroll`, it should be `auto`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it has the same behavior as at the begining. And `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined `.

Comment: sorry I forget to include jquery, fixed!

Comment: Still not woring for me. ^^

Comment: I've tested on chrome and firefox and it works: obviously, first time only, I haven't include a check when windows resize or something else.. if you try to resize result window until scrollbar is visible, and the click run again, you'll see that works..

Comment: Ok ! But it's only at load, not during the session. I only have to add an event on resize ?

Comment: yes, just the first time. If you want that works on window resize, for instance, you have to add the control inside this code
: $( window ).resize(function() {
 /* check */
});

Comment: Isn't that awesome ? x) I would have prefer a full JS solution, but I found a substitute to your `hasScrollBar()` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880381/check-whether-html-element-has-scrollbars

Answer (score 1):

Use a percentage-based width, which adapts to scrollbars automatically. 390/400 is 97.5%, this should do:

```
width: 97.5%;
```

Here's your fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzngV/7/

Comment: Easy and elegant solution, but it reduces the width of the content.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `vw` and `vh` values. More info [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).