# Apply specific styling for divs having a scrollbar with css selectors

Tags: html, css

I want to add specific styling for divs having a scrollbar, is there a way to select all divs that have a scrollbar? Can I **use pseudo-element-selector** for that?

For example?

```
div.has-scrollbar {background-color:red; }
div.no-scrollbar {background-color:green; }
```

To be clear, I don't want to style the scrollbar itself.

I tried something like this:

```
div:not(::-webkit-scrollbar)
```

Comment: Maybe these help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880381/check-whether-html-element-has-scrollbars

Comment: @NHerwich that would be an option, but trying to do it completly in css

Comment: Oh, I don't think that's possible. But I wish it would be, because I am having the same issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
body {
scrollbar-base-color: #000000;
scrollbar-face-color: #000000;
scrollbar-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-arrow-color: #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-highlight-color: #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-dark-shadow-color: #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-3d-light-color: #FFFFFF;
scrollbar-track-color: #FFFFFF;}
```

I hope it was helpful

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. It styles all the scrollbars